# Is this parallel?

Tags: parallelism

> Getting attacked by a wolf, not having enough food in the winter, and my friend’s marriage were depressing times.

Is this parallel?  I think the first two are called gerund phrases and the last one is a noun phrase.  Can gerund phrases be parallel with noun phrases?

Comment: No problem per se, but there are two punctive events and a state, which stretches a single usage of 'times'. 'Getting attacked by a wolf, not having enough food in the winter one year, and my friend’s wedding are memorable episodes in my history.' 'Baking cakes, knitting jumpers, and archery are my favourite pastimes.'

Comment: You could say *A wolf attack, a food shortage in winter, and my friend's marriage were depressing times* But do you mean your friend's (perhaps short) time while married or the events surrounding his getting married/marriage ceremony?

Comment: "My friend's marriage" can mean different things. The marriage itself is a noun. But it can also mean "my friend's series of actions and interactions with his wife."  That is, the relationship actions of the marriage. Which, guessing from context, could imply that his wife was a wolf who attacked him, or that she kept him from having enough food.